# publish django project where i use websocket

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, gunicorn, channel

While my django project is working in local, when I try to publish it with dajngo and nginx, it still works but cannot connect to websocket.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/oasis  **

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 34.224.212.102;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Youtube_video_downloader/myproject.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Youtube_video_downloader/myproject.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service **

```
Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Youtube_video_downloader

ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/Youtube_video_downloader-SjipcW-q/bin/gunicorn access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/Youtube_video_downloader/myproject.sock video_downloader.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```